# When a const variable is no longer valid outside a block, is the memory it points to also invalid?

Tags: javascript

I know that const is block scoped - the variable shouldn't exist outside the block it's defined in.

In the following code:

```
function createElement (tag, text) {
    const el = document.createElement(tag);
    el.textContent = text;
    return el; //shouldn't this be returning a reference to variable el?
}

const aquaman = createElement('li','Aquaman'); //el shouldn't exist here, but aquaman is now assigned to the reference to el. isn't this a memory leak?
```

I'm confused as to why this is OK.
`el` should be a reference to the space in memory that `createElement` allocates.
the method is returning a pointer to that object, right?
typeof(aquaman) > "object", which tells me that aquaman is also a pointer, but is this a pointer to the same part of memory that was allocated by the `document.createElement` method?

from my understanding, const variables are only valid in the block they are declared/defined in. So just because the variable is no longer valid, that doesn't necessarily mean that the block of memory that the variable is pointing to is also invalid?

Comment: If `const` variables going out of scope could invalidate memory, `const foo = [1,2,3]; { const tmp = foo; } console.log(foo);` would invalidate the `foo` array at the `}`.

Comment: It's a "leak" in the same way a factory function would create a memory leak.  You purposefully want to use something created by `createElement` and are keeping the reference to the created element around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects are not destroyed until all references to them are gone and garbage collected. When the object is returned, the calling code obtains a reference to it, and the object is not garbage collected. So when you return `el` you have a reference to it in the calling block, and thus the object is not destroyed - the memory is valid.

Comment: I see.
So this means that when my createElement function is initially declared, this callable function will live in memory forever (until the application is closed). the el variable, a pointer, within the function only lives during the execution of the function, and is garbage collected at some point after we leave the function. but the memory it points to will live as long as the aquaman variable lives.

Comment: If there are references to the memory it will live - If all references are gone out of scope - the memory will be freed. So don't worry - if you have a reference to a variable its memory will be valid, and otherwise you can't even access the memory to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

"So just because the variable is no longer valid, that doesn't necessarily mean that the block of memory that the variable is pointing to is also invalid?"

Correct.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const):

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It
>   does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable
>   identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the
>   content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its
>   parameters) can be altered.